# JavaScript nested map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array:

```
const array = [
  {name: "abc", numbers:[1,2]},
  {name: "def", numbers:[3,4]}
];
```

I want to use `.map()` to return a new array like:

```
[
  {name:"abc", number:1},
  {name:"abc", number:2},
  {name:"def", number:3},
  {name:"def", number:4}
]
```

What should I do?

Comment: do u want to return a copy of the array?

Answer (score 2):

It would be more performant to use `forEach` instead of `map`.

As @MohammadUsman's nice answer shows, the output of `map` has to be flattened before you can get the result you want. With `forEach` (which returns nothing), you can just append to the output array directly:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "abc", numbers: [1,2] },
  { name: "def", numbers: [3,4] }
];

var result = [];
              
data.forEach(
  ({ numbers, ...rest }) => numbers.forEach(
    n => result.push(Object.assign({number: n}, rest )))
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over input array using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to generate new object and finally flat the array using [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get the desired output.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "abc", numbers: [1,2] },
  { name: "def", numbers: [3,4] }
];
              
const result = data.map(
  ({ numbers, ...rest }) => numbers.map(n => Object.assign({number: n}, rest ))
).flat();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take directly [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with an inner mapping of new objects and get an array of objects.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: "abc", numbers:[1, 2] }, { name: "def", numbers:[3, 4] }],
    result = array.flatMap(({ name, numbers }) => numbers.map(number => ({ name, number })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` if `flatmap` not available. It is faster in your cases. Iteration will be only one time for each element.

```js
const array = [
  { name: "abc", numbers: [1, 2] },
  { name: "def", numbers: [3, 4] },
];
const results = array.reduce((r, item) => {
  r = r.concat(item.numbers.map((number) => ({ name: item.name, number })));
  return r;
}, []);
console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution if you are up for using jquery...

```
const array = [
               {name: "abc", numbers:[1,2]},
               {name: "def", numbers:[3,4]}
              ];

var newArray = [];
$.each(array, function(k,v){
  var strName = v.name;
    $.each(v.numbers, function(key,value){
        newArray.push({name: strName, number: value});
  });
});


console.log(newArray);
```